# Create JWT without kid in header

Tags: c#, .net, jwt

I write code to generate JWT and sign it with certificate, but it add `kid` attribute in header witch I don't want. How to create JWT signed with certificate without this attribute? Here is my code:

```
public string CreateToken(string thumbprint, string iss, string sub, string aud, int lifetime)
    {
        X509Certificate2 cert = null;

        var certificateStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        var lifeDuration = new Lifetime(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(lifetime));
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        certificateStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        foreach (var certificate in certificateStore.Certificates)
        {
            if (certificate == null || certificate.Thumbprint == null)
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (string.Equals(certificate.Thumbprint, thumbprint, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                certificateStore.Close();
                cert = certificate;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (cert == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Certificate cannot be found!");
        }

        var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new X509SecurityKey(cert), SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature);

        var tokenDescriptor = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {

            Issuer = iss,
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim("sub", sub),
                    new Claim("jti", Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                }),
            Audience = aud,
            Expires = lifeDuration.Expires,
            SigningCredentials = signingCredentials
        };

        Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityToken token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

        string tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

        return tokenString;
    }
```

Code above generate this token:

```
{
 "alg": "RS256",
 "kid": "B8C72D1B7A713A09372F2376094CC525A023379C",
 "typ": "JWT"
}
{
 "jti": "216fcf32-d4ae-4b5a-a255-79733b2e4535",
 "exp": "1506496792",
 "iat": "1506496792",
 "iss": "issuer",
 "aud": "audience",
 "sub": "subject"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've changed my method to look like this and now it works fine

```
public string CreateToken(string thumbprint, string iss, string sub, string aud, int lifetime)
    {
        var lifeDuration = new Lifetime(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(lifetime));
        var cert = this.FindCertificate(thumbprint);
        var signingCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new X509SecurityKey(cert), SecurityAlgorithms.RsaSha256Signature);

        JwtHeader header = new JwtHeader(signingCredentials);
        header.Clear();
        header.Add("alg", "RS256");
        header.Add("typ", "JWT");

        JwtPayload payload = new JwtPayload(
            iss, 
            aud, 
            new List<Claim>()
            {
                new Claim("sub", sub),
                new Claim("jti", Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
            }, 
            null, 
            lifeDuration.Expires);

        var jwt = new JwtSecurityToken(header, payload);
        var encoded = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(jwt);

        return encoded;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!  The essence of the solution is the call to `header.Clear()` after initializing the `JwtHeader` and then setting the headers you want.